# Jersey(1.7.1) Rest API's not working on open shift + Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0)

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jersey, openshift

This is how my pom.xml is the same project is working on my local machine...

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>appartment</groupId>
<artifactId>appartment</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>asdf</name>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>eap</id>
        <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>eap</id>
        <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
            invoking mvn. -->
        <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
            will need. -->
        <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'webapps' 
            folder. -->
        <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
        <id>openshift</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>appartment</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                        <warName>ROOT</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and my log file looks like below..nothing suspicious

```
Oct 29, 2015 3:07:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina     addClusterRuleSet
INFO: Cluster RuleSet not found due to [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.ha.ClusterRuleSet]. Cluster configuration disabled.
Oct 29, 2015 3:07:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina addClusterRuleSet
 INFO: Cluster RuleSet not found due to [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.ha.ClusterRuleSet]. Cluster configuration disabled.
 Oct 29, 2015 3:07:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
 INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal    performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path:    /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/lib64:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
Oct 29, 2015 3:07:12 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
 INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.5.28.129-8080"]
 Oct 29, 2015 3:07:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
 INFO: Initialization processed in 1668 ms  
 Oct 29, 2015 3:07:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  startInternal
 INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 29, 2015 3:07:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
Oct 29, 2015 3:07:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/openshift/562f19927628e1ba7800016d/app- root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/ROOT.war
Oct 29, 2015 3:07:13 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/openshift/562f19927628e1ba7800016d/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Oct 29, 2015 3:07:23 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.controller.appartment
  org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs
Oct 29, 2015 3:07:23 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
 class com.controller.appartment.AuthenticationEndpoint
Oct 29, 2015 3:07:23 AM     com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig  logClasses
INFO: Provider classes found:
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonParseExceptionMapper
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonMappingExceptionMapper
 Oct 29, 2015 3:07:24 AM     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.17.1 02/28/2013 12:47 PM'
Oct 29, 2015 3:07:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive    /var/lib/openshift/562f19927628e1ba7800016d/app-   root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/ROOT.war has finished in 17,878 ms
Oct 29, 2015 3:07:30 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.5.28.129-8080"]
Oct 29, 2015 3:07:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 18389 ms
```

I am using jersey 1.7.1 and the same application works fine in my localmachine but when deployed in openshift it is giving 404 error,its not even recognizing the api's  i tried even simple url based harcoded api,still it doesnt work :-(
Does any one face similar issue ?any helping hand would be appreciated.

Comment: It shows in the log only one resource class being loaded, the `AuthenticationEndpoint`. Is that the only one you have and are trying to access?

Comment: @peeskillet yes i am tryng to access the api which is in AuthenticationEndpoint class